# Apache basic authentication issue with reverse proxy

Tags: apache, authentication, ubuntu, jenkins, reverse-proxy

I want to add basic authentication for a reverse proxy site of Apache running on Ubuntu server 12.04.1.

The web application is [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) that is running on a Java EE container.

I added below configurations in **httpd.conf**,

```
ProxyPass         /jenkins/  http://localhost:8080/jenkins/¬
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins/  http://localhost:8080/jenkins/¬
ProxyRequests     Off¬
ProxyPreserveHost On¬ 
¬
<Proxy http://localhost:8080/jenkins*>¬
  Order deny,allow¬
  Deny from all¬
▸ AllowOverride AuthConfig¬
▸ AuthType Basic¬
  AuthName "jenkins"¬
▸ AuthBasicProvider file¬
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passfile¬
▸ Require valid-user¬
▸ Satisfy any¬
</Proxy>
```

When I used wrong password or non-exist username for authentication, I can find below messages in **error.log** of apache,

> [Sat Oct 27 17:51:59 2012] [error] [client 222.128.175.95] user kane:
>   authentication failure for "/jenkins/": Password Mismatch [Sat Oct 27
>   17:52:04 2012] [error] [client 222.128.175.95] user Aladdin not found:
>   /jenkins/

There is no message will be logged when using right user and password in ***passfile***. Though I input right user and password in web browser, the authentication dialog will prompt again.
I also found below output in **access.log** of apache,

> 222.128.175.95 - kane [27/Oct/2012:17:39:54 +0800] "GET /jenkins/ HTTP/1.1" 401 794 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2)
>   AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94
>   Safari/537.4"

Does anybody know how to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have authentication enabled on Jenkins as well? See this link: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Apache+frontend+for+security for instructions on setting this up.

Particularly note the line which says that you cannot have security enabled in Jenkins and Apache simultaneously as the two will conflict, causing the infinite prompt you are seeing. Unfortunately you have to choose one or the other.

Also see this link for a more general discussion of Apache + Jenkins setup: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. My jenkins indeed uses OpenId for authentication as well. Because the limitation of Jenkins CLI I have to make some job can be read by anonymous user. That's why I want to use basic authentication for my jenkins that is behind Apache server. Looks like jenkins has conflict between its authentication and Apache basic authentication. Anyway it gives me a explaination.

Comment: I know this post is 3 years old but I found it while searching for a solution. If you want prevent Jenkins from showing infinite basic auth prompts just add `RequestHeader unset Authorization` in your Apache config. See full solution here: http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/SOLVED-Apache-SSL-Proxy-Jenkins-tp4700182p4700212.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this config

```
ProxyPass         /jenkins/  http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins/  http://localhost:8080/jenkins/
ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy http://localhost:8080/jenkins*>
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    AuthName            "jenkins"
    AuthBasicProvider   file
    AuthType            basic
    AuthUserFile        /etc/apache2/passfile
    <Limit GET POST>
        require valid-user      
    </Limit>
    Satisfy all
</Proxy>
```

Comment: There is no authentication required any more in browser. I think it's caused by `Order allow,deny
    allow from all`, which allows all access.

Comment: deny from all: it blocks all access including the authentication, you can see this link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html

Comment: You can put IP address range instead of "all" to be able to make authentication, example: Allow from 10.1.0.0/16

Comment: the problem is caused by "Satisfy any" you can remove it or remplace it by "Satisfy All"

Comment: "Satisfy Any" Allows the request if any requirement is met, but "Satisfy All" Allows the request only if both requirements are met, you can see my update above

Comment: It still does not work. The authentication dialog always pops up even I entered the correct password.

Comment: how you created your user?, may be you should recreate your user by using htpasswd command

Comment: the syntax of htpasswd command like this: "htpasswd -bm /etc/apache2/passfile Aladdin password"

Comment: I'm sure the passfile is fine. Because another site is using same file for basic authentication that is not a reverse proxy. And I also mentioned in my question, the **error.log** can find _password mismatch_ or _user not found_ messages when I input wrong password or non-existing user. When I used correct user and password, nothing was logged in it. But the authentication dialog will be prompted again and again.